# Proving $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ when $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am struggling to find an explicit bijection $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ when $\mathbb{N}$, by definition, includes $0$. If $\mathbb{N}$ were to exclude $0$, I could note that any positive integer can be written uniquely in the form $2^{a-1} (2b - 1)$ and then map $(a,b) \to n$. Including $0$, I have to change $a - 1$ to $a$ and $2b - 1$ to $2b + 1$, but I still run into the issue of what to map to $0$. I can't map $(0,0)$ to $0$, for example, because $2^{0} (2(0) - 1) = 1$ is the unique element of the form $2^{a-1} (2b - 1)$ mapping to $1$.

Does anyone have any tips for how to repair this bijection?

Comment: Can you find a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$? If you can, you can just run that bijection 'both ways' — on the input, go $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\to\mathbb{N}$ to translate your inputs into the ones you know how to handle, and then on the output go $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ to map back.

Comment: If you have bijection $f:\mathbb N_+ \times \mathbb N_+ \to \mathbb N_+$ and by $g:\mathbb N_+ \to \mathbb N$ you denote bijection $g(n) = n-1$, similarly with $h:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N_+ \times \mathbb N_+$ by formula $h(n,m) = (n+1,m+1)$ then composition $g \circ f \circ h : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ will work

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179491/explicit-bijection-between-mathbb-n-and-mathbb-n-times-mathbb-n or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222709/inverting-the-cantor-pairing-function for some other bijections that work.

Comment: So am I correct in thinking that if I want to include $0$, I need to in some sense 'compose bijections', i.e., this map can't be defined piece-wise? That came to mind, but I was hoping there was a simpler approach. By injectivity of the original map, it makes sense to me that this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: " I can't map (0,0) to 0, for example, because 20(2(0)−1)=1 is the unique element of the form 2a−1(2b−1) mapping to 1."  So juist subtract $1$ from the results.

Comment: You've got something mapping to $N$ without $0$.  SO just substract $1$ from every result and you get somthing mapping to $N$ *with* the $0$.

Comment: You do $\mathbb N_0\to \mathbb N_1$ via $n+1$ and $N_1 \to N_0$ via $n-1$.  So.... just do it.  $N_1 \to N_1 \to N_1$ via $2^a(2b-1)$ works.  So $N_0\to N_0\to N_1$ via $2^{a+1}(2b+1)$ works and $N_0\to N_0 \to N_0$ via $2^{a+1}(2b+1)-1$.

Comment: "compose bijections', i... That came to mind, but I was hoping there was a simpler approach. "  As one of the bijections being composed is "adding/subtracting one" the composition is pretty dang simple.  You just add one to the $a,b$ and then subtract one from the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just.... combine.

You have $f:\mathbb N_{1} \times \mathbb N_1 \to \mathbb N_1$ via $f(a,b) = 2^{a-1}(2b-1)$.

And you have $g:\mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_1$ via $g(n) = n+ 1$.

So you have $g\times g: \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_1 \times \mathbb N_1$ via $g\times g(a,b) = (g(a), g(b)) = (a+ 1, b+1)$ and

You have $f\circ g\times g:  \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_1 \times \mathbb N_1 \to \mathbb N_1$ via $f\circ g\times g (a, b) = f(a+1, b+1) = 2^a(2b + 1)$.

And you have $g^{-1}\circ f\circ g\times g: \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_1 \times \mathbb N_1 \to \mathbb N_1\to \mathbb N_0$ via $g^{-1}\circ f\circ g\times g(a,b) = g^{-1} (f(a+1,b+1)) = 2^a(2b+1) -1$.

======

Alternatively the other standard bijection (that works on the cross product of any two countable sets) is to simply list pairs by weaving a diagonal path:

$(1,1), (2,1), (1,2), (3,1), (2,2),(1,3),(4,1), (3,2),(2,3),(1,4), (5,1),(4,2).....(4,2),(1,5), (6,1),(5,2)....,(2,5),(1,6),(7,1).....\to$

$1,2,3,4,5,7......$

Then just adding the index $0$ does not change anything significant.

$(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),..... \to $

$0,1,2,3,4,5,6....$

The trouble is we aren't actually *explicitely* defining what the algebraic expression of the bijection is; just showing intuitively it must exist.  But then again there is nothing in the definition that says we *have* to define what the bijection is and if we can demonstrate via induction that it exists that is fine.

But with little math we can get the first one is:

For any $(1,k)$ we map $(1,k) \to \sum_{j=0}^k = j$.  And so for the following next batch $(k+1, 1)$ to $(1, k+1)$ we map $(a=(k+1)-(b-1), b)\mapsto (\sum_{j=0}^k j) + b$.... of $(a,b)\to [\sum_{j=0}^{a+b-1} j] + b = \frac {(a+b-1)(a+b)}2 + b= \frac {(a+b)^2+(b-a)}2$.

The second is similar.

If $k = a+ b+ 1$ then $(0, a+b)\mapsto [\sum_{j=0}^k j]-1 = \frac {(a+b+1)(a+b+2)}2 - 1 = \frac{(a+b)^2 +3(a+b)}2 + 1$ and $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{(a+b)^2 +3(a+b)}2 + 1- a = \frac {(a+b)^2 + (a+3b) +2}2$

It may or may not be worth noting with shifiting indexes.

The first $\frac {(a+b)^2+(b-a)}2$ becomes $\frac {(a+1+b+1)^2 - (b-1-a+1)}2-1$ is the same as the same as the second.